# Query Logic for Count for employee late arrivals for every month in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am making a SP for counting late arrivals of each employee per month. The issue i am facing is i cannot get the last punchout time when the user sits after 12:00am as our time machine requires forced punched out before 12:00am if you are going to sit even after that. and again we have to punch in at 12:05am. The query i have made till yet is given below:

```
SELECT  ( CASE WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), PunchInTime, 108) <= '09:05'
AND CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(day, -1, PunchOutTime), 108) < '20:00'
      THEN 'On Time'
      WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), PunchInTime, 108) > '09:05'
      AND CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(day, -1, PunchOutTime), 108) < '20:00'
      THEN 'Late'
      WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), PunchInTime, 108) <= '09:05'
      AND CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(day, -1, PunchOutTime), 108) < '21:00'
      THEN 'On Time'
      WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), PunchInTime, 108) <= '10:05'
      AND CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(day, -1, PunchOutTime), 108) < '21:00'
      THEN 'On Time'
      WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), PunchInTime, 108) > '10:05'
      AND CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(day, -1, PunchOutTime), 108) < '21:00'
      THEN 'Late'
      WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), PunchInTime, 108) <= '10:35'
      AND CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(day, -1, PunchOutTime), 108) < '22:00'
      THEN 'On Time'
      WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), PunchInTime, 108) > '10:35'
      AND CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(day, -1, PunchOutTime), 108) < '22:00'
      THEN 'Late'
      WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), PunchInTime, 108) <= '02:05'
      AND CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(day, -1, PunchOutTime), 108) >= '22:00'
      THEN 'On Time'
      WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(5), PunchInTime, 108) > '02:05'
      AND CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(day, -1, PunchOutTime), 108) BETWEEN '22:00' AND '00:00'
      THEN 'Late'                 
      ELSE 'No record found'
      END ) AS Status, *
        FROM    dbo.LaunchPad_TimeHistory ;
```

Here I am using `day - 1` logic but it fails in that scenario as date changes at that employee punchout. Kindly help in this regard.

Table Structure is:

```
Status  ID  EmpID  PunchInTime              PunchOutTime                 LastAccessTime         ForcedPunchOut  Notes
On Time  1   100   2015-04-23 18:00:00:0000 2015-04-23 18:00:00:0000      2015-04-23 12:23:41      0           ABC
```

Comment: please post your table structure sample input and expected output.

Comment: expected output is just the count figure of all the bits which will increment daily to show that you have been late 5 times this month or 6 times this month.

Comment: So There is one row per employee per day?

Comment: yes normally one but when he punched out at 12:00 am and again punched in at 12:05 for late sittings then 2 more columns of punch in and punch out time will be added. Now i have to get that last punch-out on which i can calculate his/her late arrival as per our time slabs. I am a bit newbie to databases and need some help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your query primarily needs to check whether an employee has (punch out - punch in ) ~ 11 hours. In that case, it would be better if you entirely restucture the query only to validate the below condition:
(punch in time +  # of hours employee is expected to work )  <= punch out time.

The DB will handle all the necessary conversion (next day/ prior day) as long as the input data is being captured as a timestamp.

Since a new row will be added for the forced punch-out scenario, you can first create an intermediate table that will hold only the punch in data by discarding all punch entries that are logged between 12:00 AM and 5:00 AM ( assuming that nobody really clocks in that early for work!).

```
with base_punch_in as ( 
select id#, empID, PunchInTime 
from dbo.LaunchPad_TimeHistory 
where PunchInTime not between '12:05:00' and '05:00:00' )

select a.PunchInTime, b.PunchOutTime, empID
from   base_punch_in a 
inner join
       dbo.LaunchPad_TimeHistory b
on     a.empID = b.empID
and    b.PunchOutTime > a.PunchInTime
and    timestampdiff(b.PunchOutTime - a.PunchInTime ) <= 24 hours;
```

The last bit needs a bit of update for the correct syntax for reporting the difference in timestamps in hours